# how to write command line pipeline in ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line

I would like to create a shell-script like pipeline using command line commands in ruby.  So I have a few steps in the pipeline, each step is a command line like commands (using a particular tool and the usual input and output files, like run xtool -i xx -o xxx).

Thanks in advance

Mark

Comment: so just to finish off my message, anyone has any ideas how to do this?

Comment: This is worded quite confusingly, do you mean that `xtool -i xx -o xxx` would be equivalent to `xx | xxx`?

Comment: My _guess_ is that @Mark is asking how to write Ruby scripts that gracefully consume input and produce output in ways that can be chained together. (This question is not clear, however.)

Comment: You can [edit] your question, you know.

Answer (score 3):

You can run external programs by quoting with backticks or using %x:

```
x = `echo "hello"`
y = %x{echo "hello"}
```

You can look at the last process through `$?`:

```
`rm an_existing_file`
$?.exitstatus # now: o

`rm missing_file`
$?.exitstatus # now: 1
```

If you need to do anything more complex, look at the [Ruby Process Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Process.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know what you are asking, but if you want to write a Ruby command-line app that can be used in a pipeline on the command line, but also possibly use command-line arguments, you can do this:

```
require 'optparse'

input = STDIN
output = STDOUT
option_parser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  options.on("-i FILE","Input file (defaults to stdin)") do |filename|
    input = File.new(filename)
  end
  options.on("-o FILE","Output file (defaults to stdout)") do |filename|
    output = File.new(filename,'w')
  end
end

option_parser.parse!

input.readlines.each do |line|
  # do something with line
  output.puts "Some awesome output"
end
output.close # NOTE, this must be the last line of your program since
             # you are possibly closing the standard output
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have `sh` and `system` kernel methods. You can write your own shell script and invoke it using `system('yourscript.sh')`.

`system` returns true if the command gives zero exit status, false otherwise.